# How to use contact form-7 wordpress short code inside amp html and php?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, amp-html

I have saved my file `contact.php` into server and am making `amp` page of contact form

```
    <div>
        <?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="4" title="Contact form 1 col FR"]' ); ?>
    </div>
```

using this code i goot an error like this:

```
--> Undefined function 'do_shortcode'.
```

How can I avoid this error?

Comment: Is ```contact.php``` a template or it's an separate file? If it's separate file then you need to include ```wp-load.php``` from root wordpress folder before calling this function.

Answer (score 0):

The function `do_shortcode` is only available when a file is executed in wordpress-context. So if `contact.php` is called directly, ensure to add a `include('wp-load.php');` at the beginning of the `contact.php`.

The file `wp-load.php` is placed on the same level as `wp-config.php`, so depending on the file-location of your `contact.php` you need to change the path for example to something like this: `include(__DIR__ . '/../../wp-load.php');`

Comment: Thank's !  This file is not a part of wordpress, because this is simple html file has saved into contact.php then how to get shortcode data into html page .

Comment: That's not going to work in any reasonable way. To use WordPress plugin shortcodes, you're going to want to use WordPress. Make that HTML page into a page template or something similar and life will be far easier.